# My windows 10 pc wakes up on its own after going to sleep

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep, power-management, windows-10-v1703

So, I have a Windows 10 PC that, after W10 creators update, started having the following problem:

whenver I put the PC to sleep, the PC goes to sleep and stays sleeping for about 30 seconds... then it wakes up again!
If I put it back to sleep after that, there's a 50/50 chance it will wake up again on its own.
Once I put it to sleep a third time, it usually stays asleep correctly.

I know problems with sleep are very common with windows (been having them, in one form or another, since the win vista days), but is there any way I can at least diagnose WHAT is causing the interruption of sleep?

Comment: Are you moving your mouse?

Comment: @DavidPostill that question is so bad in many ways, yet it is valid... How weird is that! Though I guess I would rephrase it as: "Is it possible your mouse detects motion and wakes your computer?"

Comment: @DavidPostill : I'll tets this for sure in a few hours when I get home, but I'm 99% sure that mouse movement doesn't wake the PC, only clicking it does. But now that you point it out I'm not 100% sure, so I'll get back to you when I test it, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @LPChip Agreed. Much better phrasing!

Comment: Well, turns out that no, mouse has nothing to do with it. Other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem occur after installing the creators update. I fixed it by going into Device manager/ Network adaptors/ Properties/ power management/ uncheck allow this device to wake computer.